# Как из строки с датой в формате 'dd.mm.yyyy ' получить обьект с датой JS?

Tags: javascript

Как из такой строки с датой  `dd.mm.yyyy` получить обьект с датой, такого типа как возвращает `new Date()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если формат всегда один (`dd.mm.yyyy`), то можно регулярным выражением привести его в "валидный" вид, например *20.10.2018 > 2018/10/20* и уже такую строку передать в *new 
 Date()*. На выходе получим тот формат, что Вам и требуется.

```js
let mydate = '20.10.2018';

mydate = new Date(mydate.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, '$3/$2/$1'));

console.log(mydate.toDateString()); // Sat Oct 20 2018
```

Или, как вариант, через *[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)*.
Но, обратите внимания на `mydate[1] - 1`. Месяц при такой передачи в *Date* считается от 0 *(Январь - 0 .. итд)*, поэтому, отнимаем единицу у *10* и получаем нужный нам месяц.

```js
let mydate = '20.10.2018'.split('.');
mydate = new Date(mydate[2], mydate[1] - 1, mydate[0]);

console.log(mydate.toDateString());
```